# How to use Reactjs with rails application in the proper way

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I am a Ruby on Rails developer. Now I've just started with `Reactjs`. I am really new to this front-end framework. I wonder that should I write all my `.html` file to `.js.jsx` file?

I see in rails there are many view helpers such as form, nested form, pagination, .... But if I move to Reactjs, do I have to rewrite these in javascript? 
Paginate is too simple in rails with `gem will_paginate`, but maybe too complex to rewrite in Reactjs.

These all what I wonder should I use reactjs? what are the advantages? 
How to use `Reactjs` in suitable way?

Answer (score 0):

I really like to separate front-end and back-end projects:

- Two developers with different skills can work together (you don't need full-stack developers)
- You can change your front-end/back-end framework easily
- Your code will be really clean
- You can have same back-end for all front-ends (web, android, iOS, ...)
- You can develop them as separate project and you don't need to wait for rials development. You can go with API dummy sever.

With integration of react and rails maybe you will be fast at first but you won't be scalable as much as separate one.